# Warning about incorrect packing pragma

Tags: c, gcc, clang, pragma

How can I get GCC or Clang to warn me about the error below, where `M` was supposed to be `N` in line 2?

Even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wunknown-pragmas`, none of these compilers emit any sort of warning.

```
#define N 4
#pragma pack(push, M)

int main() {
  return 0;
}

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: #ifndef M
    #error M not defined
#endif

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot know your intentions, only if the code is valid. You can check up on yourself with this

```
#ifndef M
    #error M not defined
#endif
```

Or if `M` was defined separately from `N` with this

```
#if M != N
    #error M is not N
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of the preprocessor the pragma is not evaluated ie if you add `N` you won't get a `4` after the preprocessor is done.

I don't think you can have it warn here, at least not easily, maybe a preprocessor wizard might be able to figure it out. The following warning does not help unless it's in an undefined value in an `#if` statement.

```
-Wundef
```

If you try and add anything to the pragma ie

```
#pragma pack(push, (M + 0))
```

You get a warning because the pragma is expecting an integer or identifier ie

```
warning: expected integer or identifier in '#pragma pack'
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the `M` identifier will be handled in the same way in a `#pragma` as it would be in an `#ifdef` directive.  Although that seems plausible, the standard leaves it completely up to the implementation, as far as I can tell.  Do you have any GCC or Clang docs that support your conclusion?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're correct, it's not handled the same on clang, it's not evaluated as far as I can tell.